# EaselJS Change Color onMouseOver

Tags: html, canvas, mouseover, easeljs

I switched over to EaselJS after having muleheadedly implemented all mouse and vector related information in the HTML canvas element.

I have gotten used to EaselJS and it is really neat. I especially like the containers and how simple they make drawing embedded shapes. However, I can't figure out how you, for example, implement a color change of a [shape](http://www.easeljs.com/docs/Shape.html) on a mouse over. Anything as simple as a rectangle changing color from red to green.

Am I supposed to remove the shape from its container and create a new shape with the new color?

To complicate matters, if one shape partially occludes another, lets say a square inside a circle, then onMouseOver will not register for the circle when over the square. Is there any way around this.

Cheers

EDIT: here is an example of the vector I use to draw my circle

```
    var circle=new Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginStroke("rgba(255,0,0,0.75)")
            .setStrokeStyle(lw)
            .drawCircle(w/2,h/2,r)
            .endStroke()
            .beginFill("rgba(255,255,0,0.5)")
            .drawCircle(w/2,h/2,r-lw/2)
            .endFill();
    circle.shadow=new Shadow("rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",10,-10,10)
```

Is there an easy way to pass a new color to beginFill? Can I use variable there? Does the `circle.graphics...` get executed only once, or every time there is a call to `stage.update()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the Shape.graphics.beginFill to a different color on the mouseover.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3fLUc/) (warning: sloppy code!)

Comment: Thanx for the example. In my case things are a little more complex. There is a circle with an alpha value of 0.5, therefore, simply redrawing will not suffice. Furthermore, there are shadows. I just assumed that EaselJS would have a `color` attribute, so one could easily update it. However, I suppose as Shapes have complex vectors, it is not that simple. I guess I have to 
1) call stage.clear()
2) redefine the ENTIRE vector of the shape to be recolored
3) replace old shape with this new shape
4) call stage.update()

is there an easier way? (btw, I'll include a snippet of my code)

Comment: I found the solution. Basically, all I have to do, to redraw the image is create a new Graphics instance like so `circle.graphics=new Graphics()` on every mouse over/out and change the color each time.