# Change color of shape without recreating

Tags: javascript, colors, createjs, easeljs

I have a project using easelJS in that I'm trying to simply change the color of a shape object.  I have a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978338/easeljs-change-color-onmouseover) of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836376/easeljs-change-shape-fill-color-on-mouse-click) but they both seem to indicate I would need to completely redraw the shape with a `graphics.beginFill()` call again.  This seems completely overkill considering that I've stored my shape object already and am able to perform other manipulations on it.
I've also tried to use [ColorFilter](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ColorFilter.html) and [ColorMatrix](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ColorMatrix.html) but have not had luck making a clean color change.  In some cases the color essentially "overwrites" the detail of the shape.

I have an array of `ShapeObject` that I store the `createjs.Shape()` object in.

```
    var ShapeObject = function() 
    {
            this.name;
            this.shape;
            this.rotation;
            this.color;
    };

sObject = new ShapeObject();

myShape = new createjs.Shape();
sObject.shape = myShape;

shapes = new Array();
shapes.push(sObject);
```

Later I am able to retrieve the shape from the array and apply a filter, for example,

```
    s = shapes[i];
    filter = new createjs.ColorFilter(0,0,0,1, 255,128,0,0);
    s.shape.filters = [ filter ];
```

Using this same example I'd like to avoid having to completely recreate the shape.  I have tried the following but, while it changes color, I lose all the other details of the shape that was originally applied.

```
    s.shape.graphics.clear().beginFill(color);
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to simply change the color without completely recreating the original shape?

**EDIT**

Following the answer regarding `.command` and the [createjs command blog post](http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/) I have created the following.

```
    var theShape = new createjs.Shape();

    var fillCommand = theShape.graphics.beginFill("yellow").command;

    theShape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1)
        .beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0, 0, 0))
        .drawCircle(0, 0, 20)
        .moveTo(0,-20)
        .lineTo(0,0)
        .moveTo(0,0)
        .lineTo(20,0);

    fillCommand.style = "orange";
```

Despite being nearly identical to the examples I am receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of undefined` at the last line above.

Comment: Any chance you are using an older version of EaselJS? Commands were added in 0.7.0. Here is your example using 0.8.2: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/5km8a4st/

Comment: Turns out I was using 0.7.0 so good call there.  I had followed a tutorial that had me add the cdn references but never bothered to verify the current version!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `ColorFilter` or `ColorMatrix`, it will likely be much slower. But you could use the `Graphics` command object, check out the docs: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html

```
 var fillCommand = myGraphics.beginFill("red").command;
 // ... later, update the fill style/color:
 fillCommand.style = "blue";
```

Comment: I've been through the docs quite a bit but I hasn't noticed 'command'. I'll take a look.